# Is there any pre-built exe/binary for Adobe DNG SDK?

Tags: adobe, file-format, dng

Someone might argue whether its related to photography or not, but since it is related to DNG format, asking here.

I am trying to build a Adobe DNG SDK so that I am able to convert many different camera raw formats to *.dng format.

I downloaded the Adobe DNG SDK source for [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/dng/dng_sdk.html). When extracted it, found a workspace to build that source code. It had many dependencies which I tried to get and build the DNG SDK, but no success, I keep getting errors.

Is there any place where I can get a pre-built DNG SDK or some kind of Windows/Linux binary for it?

Answer (score 2):

Just went through the same nightmare on Windows 10, and came out the other side less than an hour ago. Here's what I found you have to do, to anyone who ever wants to use the DNG SDK.

- Get MS Visual Studio 2013... not later versions!
- Follow instructions of the README.txt in the DNG SDK folder
- Open dng_sdk projects in VS
- Set configuration to x64 (not sure if vital, not willing to test it)
- Change project properties:
  Platform Toolset to "Visual Studio 2013 (v120)"... will not work with v141!
- Build

At this point you should be all set. I had a problem with the output directory not matching the location that VS thought it was, so I had to use the MS Build output statements to find the dng_validate.exe, copy it into the working directory, and run it from cmd. The .lib built just fine for me on these settings.

Hope you have a much nicer experience than my few hours of tearing my hair out over compile errors that seemed to be written into the code, but were just the result of an incorrect setup!

Comment: Note that using Visual Studio 2013 will not work with up to date versions of the sdk (as of July 2022). YOu need Visual Studio 2019 now.

Answer (score 0):

Not legally as you have to accept licenses when you download the source.

Answer (score 0):

Since I went through this journey a couple of years later, I would like to document my updated results here:

Firstly, tomwaldnz is distributing a compiled version of dng_validate together with a Java UI that he wrote around it: https://github.com/CameraAndLensReviews/AdobeDNGValidatorUI. The downside is that that version is at least 8 years old and hence does not support the latest revisions of the spec (in my test I had to go down to DNG version 1.1).

Note: I am not affiliated with that project.

Secondly, to compile an up to date version of dng_validate, here are the required steps as of July 2022:

1. Download Visual Studio 2019
2. Follow the steps in DNG_ReadMe.txt, but read the following caveats first:

   - I personally selected x64 for me, as AMD64 didn't work.
   - Decide whether you want a debug or release build and stick with that decision, as you need to build all projects in the same configuration.
   - When building the XMP-projects, always choose "Debug" or "Release" according to your previous choice, never choose "Debug DLL" or "Release DLL", those will give you build errors later, even though the build succeeds now.
3. After building `dng_validate`, you will find the `exe` in `dng_sdk_1_6\dng_sdk_1_6\dng_sdk\projects\win\dng_validate\Validate Debug\x64\dng_validate.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\kammel\Downloads\dng_sdk_1_6\dng_sdk_1_6\dng_sdk\targets\win\debug64_x64\dng_validate.exe` (not in the project's build output directory, which confused me).